# Can a sub-microsecond clock resolution be achieved with current hardware?

Tags: x86-64, clock

I have a thread that needs to process a list of items every X nanoseconds, where X < 1 microsecond. I understand that with standard x86 hardware the clock resolution is at best 15 - 16 milliseconds. Is there hardware available that would enable a clock resolution < 1 microsecond? At present, the thread runs continuously as the resolution of nanosleep() is insufficient. The thread obtains the current time from a GPS reference.

Comment: I think it depends on how much processing you need to do rather than clock resolution. Can you specify clock resolution you need? Also can you give your code? Our can you say how much time you expect it takes to execute if it's too short to be timed? It should be executed every X nanosecond or block and wait X nanoseconds every time? A long time ago I did some pretty precise stuff using RTAI Linux and not so long ago found out people were using GPIO from as Raspberry Pi to transmit radio.

Comment: @terma Actually, it was the VxWorks documentation that states the 15 - 16 millisecond limit is hardware bound.

Comment: @Elric I would prefer to have the thread sleep for around 100 nanoseconds.

Comment: @terma See: http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/timerLib.html#nanosleep

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current time with extremely high precision on x86 using the `rdtsc` instruction.  It counts clock cycles (on a fixed reference clock, not the actually dynamic frequency CPU clock), so you can use it as a time source once you find the coefficients that map it to real GPS-time.

This is the clock-source Linux uses internally, on new enough hardware.  (Older CPUs had the rdtsc clock pause when the CPU was halted on idle, and/or change frequency with CPU frequency scaling).  It was originally intended for measuring CPU-time, but it turns out that a very precise clock with very low-cost reads (~30 clock cycles) was valuable, hence decoupling it from CPU core clock changes.

---

It sounds like an accurate clock isn't your only problem, though:  If you need to process a list every ~1 us, without ever missing a wakeup, you need a realtime OS, or at least realtime functionality on top of a regular OS (like Linux).

Knowing what time it is when you do eventually wake up doesn't help if you slept 10 ms too long because you read a page of memory that the OS decided to evict, and had to get from disk.